# Tar a folder without .git files?

Tags: tar, git

If I tar a folder that is a git repository, can I do so without including the `.git` related files? If not, how would I go about doing that via a command?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Have a look at `git help archive` or `git archive --help`. The `git` subcommand `archive` allows you to make archives containing only files trackeod by `git`. This is probably what you are looking for.

One of many examples listed at the end of the manual:

```
git archive --format=tar.gz --prefix=git-1.4.0/ v1.4.0 >git-1.4.0.tar.gz
```

A current version of `git` supports creating archives in the following formats:

- `tar`
- `tar.gz` or `tgz`
- `zip`

See `git archive --list` for a list of formats supported on your system.

Comment: this only archives root git repo. If submodules were used - their directories will be empty.

Answer (score 89):

Simplest answer: Add `--exclude-vcs`. This excludes all version control system directories

Personally I use

```
tar --exclude-vcs -zcvf foo.tar.gz ./FOLDER_NAME
```

so all you need to do is add the `--exclude-vcs` at the end of the command.

Comment: All *known* ones, I suppose? ;)

Comment: All the options need to be together before the arguments on GNU/Linux.

Comment: As stated for GNU/Linux ```tar --exclude-vcs -zcvf foo.tar.gz ./FOLDER_NAME```

Comment: It seems OSX Catalina's tar doesn't support that option...

Comment: Getting a `tar: Option --exclude-vcs is not supported` in macOS

Comment: @FranMarzoa @Decy `--exclude-vcs` is only supported by gnu tar. On MacOS you can install it using brew like this `brew install gnu-tar`. Then you can run `gtar --exclude-vcs [...]`

Comment: Just to add a little more info on which VCS's are supported, [GNU tar :: 6.4 Excluding Some Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/exclude.html) states the following: `Exclude files and directories used by following version control systems: ‘CVS’, ‘RCS’, ‘SCCS’, ‘SVN’, ‘Arch’, ‘Bazaar’, ‘Mercurial’, and ‘Darcs’.` (.git included)  See more in the doc.

Answer (score 28):

If you want the archive to include the files tracked by git, but not the git repository itself or any generated or otherwise untracked file, then [use `git archive`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18657/tar-a-folder-without-git-files/18658#18658).

If you specifically want to exclude `.git` but include everything else, under Linux or FreeBSD or OSX or Cygwin, tar has a simple option to exclude a directory:

```
tar -c --exclude .git -f - foo | gzip >foo.tgz
```

With GNU tar (i.e. under Linux or Cygwin), you can shorten this to `tar czf foo.tgz --exclude .git foo`.

The POSIX way of creating archives is [`pax`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/pax.html).

```
pax -w -t -s '!.*/\.git$!!' -s '!.*/\.git/.*!!' foo | gzip >foo.tgz
```

Comment: Does `git` compiles on any system where `tar` is not available? :-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Probably not. But it does compile on systems where `tar` has no `--exclude` option, such as OpenBSD (which admittedly duplicates pax's `s` option, but that's not a common tar command syntax extension).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Good answer, I look for it for a long long time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [an answer I got on one of my questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/292436) I figured out another solution. So for completeness sake, here is a solution making use of `find`:

```sh
find . -path './.git' -prune -o -print |
  tar -czvf ../archive.tgz --no-recursion -T -
```

And if you want to exclude possible `.git` folders inside (sub)+folder:

```sh
find . -path '*/.git' -prune -o -print |
  tar -czvf ../archive.tgz --no-recursion -T -
```

Latter can be also achieved through:

```sh
find . -type d -name '.git' -prune -o -print |
  tar -czvf ../archive.tgz --no-recursion -T -
```

Quite handy if you can make use of the other filtering techniques of `find`, e.g. modification date, permissions, …

(As so often well-formed file names are assumed, otherwise you need to use null bytes as separators which can mean `-print0` for `find` and `--null` for `tar` if supported.)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me to exclude both the .git directory (and another called backups) to transfer to another server just the necessary files, it's this. Gilles answer helped me find this solution.

```
tar --exclude .git --exclude backups -czvf project1.tar.gz /var/www/html/project1/
```